# Ranking with ORDER BY DESC, but updates the column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey I have a ladder ranking with this data:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNCOO.png]

Ignore the wins, loses, lvl.

The problem is, on the team table I have a column for the ranking, the ranking I'm using on the table on the image is just a i variable that starts in 0 and increments 1 when finishes the while cyclo.
How do I update the ranking column with the real ranking ordered by Points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an `update`/`join`:

```
update rankings r join
       (select r.id, @rn := @rn + 1 as ranking
        from rankings r cross join
             (select @rn := 0) vars
        order by points desc
       ) rp
       on r.id = rp.id
    set r.ranking = rp.ranking;
```

The subquery uses variables to calculating the ranking.